# Perform Same Calculation on Dynamic Number of Columns, Each with New Variable in R

Tags: r

I would like to perform a calculation that basically checks the values of multiple dates, that will look something like the below, where if the header value of column "12/30/13" is >= Date1 and < Date2 then the value would be a 1, or if false, 0. I would like this to loop through however many columns there are on or after 12/30/13.

```
Date1      Date2      12/30/13      01/06/14      01/13/14
12/10/13   01/10/14   1             0             0
12/31/13   01/12/14   0             1             0
01/06/14   02/10/14   0             1             1
```

I am brand new to R (today) and would greatly appreciate some help. Is this possible in R? Ideas?

11/6 Update, code works for 1 column, but when I run the below, it "runs" without error but doesn't "work" (i.e. apply the changes to the column like it does when I run it on only 1 column). Ideas?

```
for (i in names(my_column_names) {
  sd[[i]] <- ifelse(is.na(sd$Field1), 0,
  ifelse(is.na(sd$Field2)
  & as.Date(sd$Field1, format = "%Y-%m-%d") < as.Date(sd[[i]], format = "%Y-%m-%d"),1,
  ifelse(as.Date(sd$Field1, format = "%Y-%m-%d") < as.Date(sd[[i]], format = "%Y-%m-%d")
  & as.Date(sd$Field2, format = "%Y-%m-%d") > as.Date(sd[[i]], format = "%Y-%m-%d"),1,0)))
}
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Usually the first step would be to get your data into a [tidy format](http://vita.had.co.nz/papers/tidy-data.pdf). In this case, you could use the `melt` function from package reshape2. When your data is tidy, the task becomes very simple.

Comment: @Roland, what if I believe my data to already by in a tidy format? (There are a lot more columns in the full data set.)

Comment: You can believe whatever you want. Per Hadley's (sensible) definition in the paper I linked to in my comment, your data is not tidy. And tidy data makes working with your data easier in R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended-up creating 2 variables to capture the column numbers I was looking for:

```
# Get colunm numbers
cs <- which(colnames(sd) == "2013-12-30")
ce <- ncol(sd)
```

And then changed the beginning of the for loop to this:

```
for (i in cs:ce) {
```

And it worked! Thanks all!